# How to change Vuetify date range picker appearance?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to recreate [these Vuetify date range pickers](http://vuetify-daterange.surge.sh/), where I have 2 pickers for From and To dates. Notice how they have a nice light blue background color, that spans through the selected range. I thought that only setting a color to the picker would be enough:

```html
<v-date-picker
  v-model="datesRange"
  color="green"
  :max="maxDate"
  no-title
  range
  @input="menuFrom = false"
/>
```

However when I created it, I see only green circles around the dates in range.

I recreated the issue in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/igal-kleiner/pen/GRZwmZN).

I tried to inspect the code at the above mentioned site, and I can see that under every `<td>` element, beside `<button>`, the have this div:

```html
<div class="date-picker-table__event date-range__date-in-range blue lighten-5"></div>
```

while I have only the button. I have no idea how they put this div in there.

I can't find anything about it in the documentation. So how can I make only the selected dates appear as green circles and the range as light green background color?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```css
div.v-picker__body.v-picker__body--no-title {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white;
}
```

[image]

its on your: [codeopen](https://codepen.io/rober19/pen/gOMPyjK)

you can debug styling like that