# How do i style the v-date-picker title to my liking

Tags: vuetify.js

Here is my code
v-date-picker

```
    <v-date-picker  
       :picker-date.sync="pickerDate"
        color="intgr"
        width="300"
       :events="events"
        class="header-text-h3"
    />
```

I didn't find any similar question
i found only such an option [How to change Vuetify date range picker appearance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63991925/how-to-change-vuetify-date-range-picker-appearance) trying to do something based on it but it did not fit

Comment: You can try with CSS overrides - but you can't really change the HTML markup that is rendered by `v-date-picker`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand where exactly I should redefine them.
I tried in <style/> with the help of the main div trying to get to the desired

Comment: You can put your CSS styles anywhere, as long as they have enough [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to overrule Vuetify's own styling.